# Cbx25uh-024-10 works in heat but not ac

Tags: hvac

I have a lennox cbx25uh-024-230-10 and the blower only runs in heat not in ac or in on mode on  thermostat. I jumped y and r on the Stat still nothing. Could it be the blower relay? Do those go out often or does it sound like the blower motor?

Comment: If the motor runs in heat mode, then the motor's good.

Comment: I wonder if it's a thermostat config problem.   Yes, furnaces/air handlers *have no awareness at all* that an A/C unit is even installed on the building.  The Y wire goes to the A/C, so the air handler doesn't know it was connected to Rc.  The thermostat must call for fan (Rh to G) when it calls for A/C.  Thermostats as a rule know this.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica -- since the fan doesn't run when the thermostat is set from AUTO to ON (at least that's how I interpret in "in on mode on thermostat"), then we have a pretty good bead that it's not the 'stat

Answer (score 3):

### It's either the blower relay or the time delay relay

Given that according to [the wiring diagram in the service manual](https://www.hvacpartsshop.com/content/lennox-furnace-manuals/cbx25uh.pdf#page=19), your air handler runs the blower motor at the same speed in all modes, it's either the blower relay itself, or the time delay relay that drives the blower relay from the G terminal input.  Note that Y is not connected to the blower logic in your air handler, so jumpering Y and R won't cause a call for blower in any case -- you need to jumper G to R to do that.

Answer (score -2):

It was the thermostat not the relays

Comment: This could be a good answer with some more information - remember that questions and answers are not just here to solve your issue, but to help others in a similar situation find help in the future. Please [edit] this answer and add some more information about how you tested to determine it was the thermostat. Also, if you're the original poster, you can try the [help] to merge your accounts and then you'll be able to accept this (edited) answer with a green check mark, to help others follow your advice next time.